# How to best model a Survey with a user model and 2 different user roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Im looking to model a survey in ruby on rails active record.
*Where there are "users" with different role ( tutor / student ).*

- Goal is using a single user model with a role column that holds "tutor", "student". T
- Then there is profile_tutor and profile_student to hold specific data depending on user role.

  ```
  user(role tutor)
     has_many sessions
     has_many responses(only used when :role => "student")

  session 
      belongs_to user(:role => "tutor")
      has_many questions

  question
      belongs_to session
      has_many responses

  response
      belongs_to_question
  ```

****User with role "student" should be able to answer questions***
What would be the best way to model this with AR and Rails?